# Inferring function signature from tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples, conditional-types

I tried for long hours now and honestly it wasn't worth the effort, bu I'd still like to see if there's a solution to this:

I'm trying to force TS to infer my function signature from tuples. I tried to play with conditional types, but I don't seem to get it right:

```js
// model
interface User {
    name: string
}

interface Article {
    title: string
}

/// api
type Resource = 'user' | 'articles'
type Params = Record<string, number | string | boolean>

type GetSignature =
    | ['user', undefined, User]
    | ['articles', { articleId: number }, Article[]]
    | ['articles', undefined, Article]

// get request
interface ObjArg {
    resource: Resource
    params?: Params
}

type RetType<TResult> = TResult & { cancel: () => void }

async function get<TResult>(args: ObjArg): Promise<RetType<TResult>>
async function get<TResult>(resource: Resource, params?: Params): Promise<RetType<TResult>>
async function get<TResult>(args: [ObjArg | Resource, Params?]): Promise<RetType<TResult>>{
    const { resource, params } = typeof args[0] === 'object' ? args[0] : { resource: args[0], params: args[1] } 
    const result = await someAsyncFetch(resource, params)
    return { ...result, cancel: () => { cancelAsyncFetch() }}
}
```

I'd like TS to be able to infer the `get`'s signature from provided arguments, so it automatically knows that e.g. when calling `get('articles', { articleId: 1 }) the return type should be`Article`as well as that I need the second argument to be of type`{articleId: number}`(or`undefined`for array of articles). This is what`GetSignature` union type should define.

So the desired usage would be something like

```js
const user = get('user') // returns User
const article = get('articles', { articleId: 1 }) // returns Article
const articles = get('articles') // returns Article[]
```

I tried dozens of approaches and none seemed to provide the interface I aim for. Just to mention one of them, I tried to expect signature as a type argument (`get<TSignature exntends GetSignature>(...)`)  and tried to infer the desired signature like in likes of this:

```js
resource: TSignature[0] extends infer T ? T : never
```

or even

```js
resource: TSignature[0] extends infer T ? Extract<GetSignature, T> : never
```

But nothing seemed to work. For now I think I'll stick to providing the type argument for `TResult`, but I'd like to know whether there a way to do what I describe in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `GetSignature` to be this:

```
type GetSignature =
    | ['user', undefined, User]
    | ['articles', { articleId: number }, Article]
    | ['articles', undefined, Article[]]
```

(note how I swapped `Article` with `Article[]` to match with what you are expecting at the end).

---

Given that, I'd probably separate out the one-arg and two-arg signatures using the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) and [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) utility types:

```
type OneArgSignatures = Extract<GetSignature, [any, undefined, any]>;
type TwoArgSignatures = Exclude<GetSignature, [any, undefined, any]>;
```

And then define the call signature for `get()` to be a pair of overloads, one for one-arg and one for two-arg calls:

```
declare function get<R extends OneArgSignatures[0]>(
    resource: R
): Extract<OneArgSignatures, [R, any, any]>[2];

declare function get<R extends TwoArgSignatures[0]>(
    resource: R,
    params: Extract<TwoArgSignatures, [R, any, any]>[1]
): Extract<TwoArgSignatures, [R, any, any]>[2];
```

You can see that the functions are generic in `R`, the resource string literal type.  Note that the compiler generally has the easiest time inferring a type parameter from a value of that type.  Inferring `TSignature` from `resource: TSignature[0] extends infer R ? R : never` is problematic, but inferring `R` from `resource: R` is straightforward.   Once `R` is inferred, the compiler can use `Extract` to calculate the type of `params` (if present) and the return type.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const u = get("user"); // User
const aa = get("articles"); // Article[]
const a = get("articles", { articleId: 123 }); // Article
```

Looks good.  Note that I didn't worry about `Promise`s, `RetType`, or your other overload.  I assume you can take care of that.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOa4C++uoksiKAglGMAgBsUeQsj5ghlarRANmuMAE8ADigDiEMAGVgdYmACuUFAF58hAD7IA2gHIDmKLYA0yAyAAmEGKAgfXGNAAuuYEVnZwvPxC6C44yJF8ghAAkh6UIAYkAEZYjK48SUIhouG2idEQsa7uXj4gfgVRydZBIQoqKADyDTx0OnpwhsboyCbIAKIAHjSIYAA8Gtq6+kYQrtZwIIo1nt6+-gnbQQB8ANwdqsgAKgDuAPZ9A6sjY5NTggZei5rPQ2sbLY7Nx7eqNI6KU4XXBeQSRFAwdwIPj3EDIOiaeYAJWQEBmEE8ox6ECeK3+I2sAAZTgAKULIEb3IxIShY3AASko01myPmxNJg2GVQ2WNcQLFxxO1gATEELrCBPDkIiQMjgKj0ZicXjIISbg8BS8qlTafTGcyKMhRfTlJFSOguTMoHN5ndHlB+mShegRRLgUDTtYAIwhTnvHkLN2G8nCmyiiF+wOy6EIVHUNxvDFgGkAIgc0Bz7LOyAA9CW0I5cKmQOm4HBM5pcxVkuhC8Wy8hCpVWlW02AEg3sznmzEc65sAlmkI0pQg9KAMzIRhF0vlrvJXBAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
type GetSignature = {
  user: [User, undefined, User]
  articles: [Article, { articleId: number }, Article[]]
}

declare function get<K extends keyof GetSignature>(type: K): Promise<RetType<GetSignature[K][0]>>
declare function get<K extends keyof GetSignature>(type: K, param: GetSignature[K][1]): Promise<RetType<GetSignature[K][2]>>
async function get(type, param) {
  ...
}
```

Playground: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUHp1wLYQCbAA2KAlgHYzBQBmAhgMbBwCqAzlYinN3GbdsABccVjCjkA5ilSkKVOozgBBWCXqEmCLjxgkYG4aPFkpMzFlpgSKGAE8wTAErBWEAK5RFAXjgByN+xQvnAAPn60quouvjb2TAAKEfyscD7O9NB4ADxGkgA0vG7YAEYcYbkmoXDFEBAatGQAfLEOcM4wACpxWR3OrG6EMI2pcL0uA-AAZIhw9A2MhMIAFACUqcMAbhAkeHAydq0A4sAwAMokEnwwHkw+WtwBVMIA2mxUBW5kBNTkwHgFbygAF1tBFdFFWC8VOCNAUEHAwWoNABJPDCMhFUpQPYFaFI4DPIEgmQEdQRJjUT70XQQMhwCQnLIAaTgoEoXxSAGtgLYINQ4MczhcrjdGksDkI4EyVsJ4lAINgSOwsu0ug4soLzpdaNcoASmUDngAGIGNZqkwjkuCUsjUki0+mMlls4AcuDc3n8zXCnWi8VxYRMgpgJLYYTe7W6-WGgCMQJlcDlCqVwBVJzVqYjIr1zwNzwATKbmiglrQAO60PSOmBLfyBXwrFYAOj4AibNUIeFWAG4S+XK-AGTXfIiIQ3m7p9MB23Uuyte6WK1Wh7XRxpWL44WvgKjhDGkI3jUCm5ONDPOz2gA